# opening a camera in middle of a screen using phonegap and html5

Tags: html, cordova

I am working on an application which requires me to start the camera in the middle of the screen. I tried using phonegap, but when I try to start a camera it opens in a new screen, which is not my usecase. I tried to do the following but it did not work.

I created a dummy div section in HTML.

On button click, I tried to replace the div element with the phonegap code. but still it takes me to a new screen.

```
function startCamera() {
    var x = document.getElementById("toBeReplacedWithCamera").innerHTML = navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
    });

}

<div id="toBeReplacedWithCamera" style="height:50%;background-color:blue;"> </div>

<td>
    <img src="unavailable.png" alt="Not Available" onclick="startCamera()"
    />
</td>
```

Comment: can you post an example code? which system are you deploying to? which version of phonegap?

Comment: This is not possible using only phonegap. You would have to write native code that created a new view that overlays content on the camera view.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon hmm, so is there any other tool through which I can attain this result. I want to develop a cross platform application which can be ported to both IOS and Android.

Comment: I have updated my post,just posted a sample code, I am trying to deploy it in both Android and IOS, and the phonegap version I am using is 3.0.